# When should I externalise XML fragments in my unit tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, embedding

A colleague and I had an interesting debate over whether XML fragments used in unit tests should live in the test file or should be externalized.

In some of the tests, we have complete XML files that are used as input, while in others we use fragments to test parts of the processing, fragments that may be 5 lines more or less in length.

My colleague argued in favor of keeping the XML there so that it is side-by-side with the testing code that is intrinsically dependent on it. I personally am opposed to two main things: the awkwardness that results from embedding XML in the source code (funny formatting, potential newline issues, having to escape characters, etc.) and the vertical impact large amounts of XML has on the source file.

I'm curious about whether there is any concrete research about the benefits of minimizing vertical usage in source control or if there are any strong arguments in favor of either approach that isn't just opinion based. I'm a heavy IDE user (IntelliJ) so maybe there are problems for more CLI-oriented users that I haven't considered?

Answer (score 1):

There are no hard rules but lack of raw strings in Java makes it look ugly. On the other hand, unless you are actually testing XML parsing, I would use external XML files only for regression and integration tests and plain java code (with or without Builders) for all other use cases. It is easier to reuse between test cases and requires less modifications in case of refactoring - IDE will make required changes in code but not in XML files/strings.